# How to detect triangle edge in opencv or emgu cv?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

[image]

I am using Emgu CV, i want to detect two sharp in the picture, first i convert the image to gray,and call cvCanny, then call FindContours， but just one contour found, the triangle not found.

Code:

```
 public static void Do(Bitmap bitmap, IImageProcessingLog log)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        using (Image<Gray, Byte> canny = new Image<Gray, byte>(gray.Size))
        using (MemStorage stor = new MemStorage())
        {
            CvInvoke.cvCanny(gray, canny, 10, 5, 3);
            log.AddImage("canny",canny.ToBitmap());

            Contour<Point> contours = canny.FindContours(
             Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
             Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE,
             stor);

            for (int i=0; contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
            {
                i++;
                MCvBox2D box = contours.GetMinAreaRect();

                Image<Bgr, Byte> tmpImg = img.Copy();
                tmpImg.Draw(box, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                log.AddMessage("contours" + (i) +",angle:"+box.angle.ToString() + ",width:"+box.size.Width + ",height:"+box.size.Height);
                log.AddImage("contours" + i, tmpImg.ToBitmap());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I don't know emguCV, but i will give you the idea)

You can do it as follows:

1. Split the image to R,G,B planes using `split()` function.
2. For each plane, apply Canny edge detection.
3. Then find the contours in it and approximate each contour using `approxPolyDP` function.
4. if number of coordinates in the approximated contour is 3, it is most likely a triangle and the values corresponds to 3 vertices of triangles.

Below is the python code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('softri.png')

for gray in cv2.split(img):
    canny = cv2.Canny(gray,50,200)

    contours,hier = cv2.findContours(canny,1,2)
    for cnt in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
        if len(approx)==3:
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2)
            tri = approx

for vertex in tri:
    cv2.circle(img,(vertex[0][0],vertex[0][1]),5,255,-1)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below is canny diagram of blue color plane:

[image]

Below is the final output, triangle and its vetices are marked in green and blue colors respectively:

[image]

Comment: why do we need to split into 3 channels? would that not work just as well after canny either on the color image? or converting to gray?

Comment: There is no need to spit. You just can convert to gray scale and use canny edge detector.