# How to get the movement of a edge by Emgucv

Tags: c#, line, emgucv, opticalflow

I am a newbie of programming. I am using emgucv for my project and now I am going to detect the movement of an edge. I may want to use this vector for further operation. However, I only find a lot of documentation on tracking the movement of features points. How can I do it on an edge?

Thx a lot.

Comment: Not my forte, but I'm assuming `Canny Edge Detection` will be a thing. I only skimmed over this but it might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424466/how-to-detect-triangle-edge-in-opencv-or-emgu-cv

Comment: @Gabe Thank you for your advice, I can create a bitmap with only edge. However, I am going to track the movement of the edge and find out the moving direction of it, how can i do it?